# Delete data using 2 DialogForm

Tags: c#, dialog

hi i have question for remove data from 2 forms dialog
in first dialogform it's contain list of data, and in second dialogform it's contain detail of data and delete button... i already successfully delete data in database but i confused how to remove data from list...

if just select data and delete i know it's can be done with this code

```
quizzes.RemoveAt(listBoxQuizzes.SelectedIndex);
```

but problem here in dialogform1 not available button delete, just view details data. so if user want to delete data, he must open dialogform2 (detail data)
i already done delete data in database with this code

```
Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Quiz_Occurrences WHERE ID = " + id);
```

and close detaildataform (dialogform2) by

```
this.Close();
```

and move to dialogform1 (listdatabox)
the problem in here, data which just i delete still in there because it's still not remove yet **(already delete from database but not remove from list)**. and need to restart program to see effect of delete data

---

**Update Progress**

i changed data to global var, so it's technically i can remove data in dialogform2
this is code (modifier listbox in dialogform1)

```
 int no = 1;
 foreach (CQuizOccurrence myQuizOccurrence in Global.quizOccurrences) {

 }
```

if i want to delete it from dialogform1, i can use

```
Global.quizOccurrences.removeAT(listBoxQuizzes.SelectedIndex);
```

but if i want to delete it from dialogform2

```
Global.quizOccurrences.removeAT(.........); //still not have idea how can i reference index
```

---

**Update** solution from @nitin

so first i write in formdialog2

```
public Frmdialog1 frm_dialog { get; set; }
```

then i write this in formdialog1

```
frmdialog2.frm_dialog=this;
```

then back again to formdialog1 to write

```
frm_dialog.quizzes.RemoveAt(frm_dialog.listBoxQuizzes.SelectedIndex);
```

is that right because i get many error

Comment: are you using a dataset or something to couple the data between forms

Comment: no...i just use simple sql to load detail data in form2

Comment: the code you show does nothing to the database. and to communicate between forms you can use events(form1 subscribe to form2 or vice versa). also Tag your question with databinding, ADO , database with type of database i.e. sqlserver or mysql

Comment: @RadioSpace yeah it's because i already finish delete data in database....all i need is remove data from listbox

Comment: Could you please try to make your question clearer? I'm not certain what your problem is (are you getting an error? is this an architectural question?).

Comment: @EricGagnon i will try, wait a minute i will edit my post

Comment: @EricGagnon is that clear enough now?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your first dialog is showing a list of items, then if the user clicks on any item in that list your program shows a second dialog which contains details about the item he selected?

Comment: @EricGagnon correct...and in detail item he delete data (database) but in listbox first dialog data still unremove until program restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm finally be able to do as i want after ask many different question about this topic
first i try to change var to global, so i can remove data in listbox dialogform1 from dialogform2 (i think it's the easiest way)

```
//in dialog form1 
foreach (CQuizOccurrence myQuizOccurrence in Global.quizOccurrences) {
   //load data from Global.quizOccurences
}
//call function close to close dialogform1
```

then in dialogform2, match Global.quizOccurrences data with date&time detail data (using list & foreach)

```
        List<CQuizOccurrence> matchData = new List<CQuizOccurrence>();
        foreach (CQuizOccurrence myQuizOccurrence in Global.quizOccurrences) 
        {
            DateTime dtDatabase = (DateTime)myQuizOccurrence.occurred;
            string dt = dtDatabase.ToString();
            if (dt == dateOccur) {
                matchData.Add(myQuizOccurrence);
            }
        }

        foreach (CQuizOccurrence myQuizOccurrence in matchData)
        {
            Global.quizOccurrences.Remove(myQuizOccurrence);
        }

        //call function show dialog for formdialog1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening second dialog from first one u can Have property in `Frmdialog2` like

```
 public Frmdialog1 frm_dialog { get; set; }
```

After creating object of `Frmdialog2` in `Frmdialog1` you can set this property as

```
frmdialog2.frm_dialog=this;
```

Now u can remove item from this listbox in `Frmdialog2` iteself after deleting record from database as

```
  frm_dialog.quizzes.RemoveAt(frm_dialog.listBoxQuizzes.SelectedIndex);
```

NOTE: Modifier for your `listbox` should be `public`

Comment: in dialogForm1 i have property frmdialog2 but in dialogform2 i havefrmdialog1 too, u sure u code ( i mean name formdialog1&2) because i confused..if this code right so it's all in dialogform1 right?

Comment: I have supposed u have 2 dialogs only and have given name accordingly

Comment: @RadioSpace can you give example why public modifier is noot good OOP? i'm still new here...and since begining (my pathner handle this project) modifier listbox already public

Comment: @Katik its just a question. some may say you should not expose internal fields to the outside. or to put it another way only form1 should know about the listbox. although I always say "whatever works!".

Answer (score 0):

form1 could subscibe to the form2's close event.

inside form1

```
form2 f2dialog = new form2(/*I guess you are passing data here*/);
f2.dialog.Closing += eventhandler;
```

somewhere else

```
void eventhandler(object sender, eventargs e)
{
 //refresh globaldata since by now you have ran delete query
 //rebind or call listbox.items.refresh() or both  <-------------this how do you get data from rver? the server is updated but does global know that?


}
```

then you need to call code to get data from database again. and rebind to data

```
listbox.datacontext = Global.GetData();//or however this is done
```

you have to manually reset this eveerytime you change your database

databinding is not as smart as you think it is.

Comment: Forgive me, but i really get hard time to understand what your solution...can u give more detail?

Comment: do you know if your data in global has changed when you run the delete query

Comment: oops typos fill fix later