# update data in listbox after deleted data without restarting program (winform)

Tags: c#, database

hi i have problem [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542101/delete-data-using-2-dialogform)
i have 2 forms, form1 contain list data and form2 contain details data, when user wanna delete data in list, user MUST open form2 (detail data) because in form1 not available function for delete, just view detail

i'm already be able to delete data in database and call close() function to close form2 after button delete pressed. and in the screen now is form1 (list data)

the problem is data which i just deleted still in there until program reboot, usually i do sometrick by remove data from listbox

```
quizzes.RemoveAt(myListBox.SelectedIndex);
```

but it's not work with that way, because it's using 2 form...(that's is what i ask in there)

in here i wanna ask different options to archive it ( i'm afraid if i ask in that question it's become 'X Y Question'), is that possible to force reloading data without need to restart aplication? if yes, can u give me example how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your form2 is DialogForm then you can reload the list when form2 is closed. Use the same code that you have used for the first time when list is filled.

Another good way to do this is using Event handlers. define a public event in form2 and raise the event when something is deleted. Add a event handler in form1 for that public event in form2.

In form2

```
public event DataDeleted(int i);
```

//after deleting some data raise event

```
if (DataDeleted!= null) {
    DataDeleted(deletedItemIndex);
}
```

And in form1

```
//when loading form2 from form1
Form2 objFrm2 = new Form2;
objFrm2.DeletedData += MyMethod;
```

//define method MyMethod

```
private void MyMethod(int i)
{
//i is index
//delete the item from list
}
```